# Create a get request via retrofit android

Tags: android, client, client-server, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an application, where I have to get a list of income messages which will be sorted into a `Listview`. I got some details of my `GET` request from server developers:

```
HTTP 200
{
    "count": int, # number of messages 
    "messages": [ # array of messages
        {
            "id": int, # message id
            "subject": str, # message subject
            "can_delete": int, # can it be deleted (1) or not (0)
            "new": int # message already read (0) or not (1)
            "date": str, # date of message in 'd.m.y'. If message was sent today format will be 'H:M'
            "receiver_name": str, # name of receiver if type=1
            "sender_name": str, # name of sender if type=0
        }, ...
    ],
    "next_url": URL,  # url for get next messages, if no more messages value is null
    "previous_url": URL # url for get previous messages, if no more messages value is null
}
```

Now I have created an `Interface`:

```
 @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @GET("/v1/message/list?type=TYPE")
    Call<List<IncomeMessages>> getInMess(@Query("count") String count,
                                         @Query("messages") String messages,
                                         @Query("id") Integer id,
                                         @Query("subject") String subject,
                                         @Query("new") Integer new_m,
                                         @Query("date") String date,
                                         @Query("receiver_name") String receiver_name,
                                         @Query("sender_name") String sender_name,
                                         @Query("next_url") URL next_url,
                                         @Query("previous_url") URL previous_url);
```

Then I have created a simple `Class` of request:

```
public class IncomeMessages
{
    @SerializedName("subject")
    private String subject;
    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("sender_name")
    private String sender_name;
    @SerializedName("receiver_name")
    private String receiver_name;

    public IncomeMessages(String sender_name, String date, String receiver_name, String subject) {
        this.sender_name = sender_name;
        this.date = date;
        this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSender_name() {
        return sender_name;
    }

    public void setSender_name(String sender_name) {
        this.sender_name = sender_name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getReceiver_name() {
        return receiver_name;
    }

    public void setReceiver_name(String receiver_name) {
        this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
    }
}
```

and right now I don't realize how I can get all of these `parameters` from the `server` and sort it into `Listview`. I also have a sample of `request:curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"` https://server/v1/message/list?type=TYPE I'm a begginer in `Retrofit` requests and maybe somebody solved similar problem previously. So I think that you will help me in solving the following problem. (Sorry for my bad English:)

Comment: you will get only the variables you declared in class in Retrofit request, in response all the data is there but the class you used doesnt have all the variables

Comment: yes, I understand it, but I can't understand how I can initialise the following interface and request class in mainactivity class???

Answer (score 1):

Here This Might Help You How Write Code in **MainActivity** in Ratrofit.

> > Retrofit will download and parse the API data on a background thread, and then return the results back to the UI thread via the onResponse or onFailure method.

```
ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ResponceClass> call = apiService.getyourInterfacemethod(); /* Here Define Mathod Name as Same as Define in Interface and Pass here Your Interface @GET or @POST Method Parameter value */
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponceClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponceClass>call, Response<ResponceClass> response) {
            //Handle Api Response Here.

            List<String> list = response.body().getResults();   /* Make Your List or Something You Want to do As Your Requirement. */
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of List Record received: " + list.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponceClass>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```